# How to add values in STL:: List container?

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, std

I'm writing a program to add values of money within a stl::list container. How could I parse through and add the values together? Thanks.

The code I want to use is below - I have added the accumulate at the bottom.

```
void readFile()
{
    string line, nuMoney, money, cents;
    unsigned long dollarSign, period;

    ifstream myfile("MONEY.txt");

    int numLines = countLines("MONEY.txt");
    //cout << "NUMLINES: " << numLines << endl;

    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: File could not be opened." << endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < numLines-1; i++)
    {
        getline(myfile, line, '\n');
        dollarSign = line.find('$');
        period = line.find('.');

        // remove commas.
        line.erase (remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ','), line.end()); 

        money = line.substr(dollarSign+1);
        //cout << money << endl;

        double MONEYS = atof(money.c_str());
        //cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << MONEYS << '\n';

        list<double> acct;
        acct.push_back(MONEYS);
    }

    int sum = accumulate(acct.begin(), acct.end(), 0);
    cout << "SUM: " << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Someone already wrote the algorithm for you: [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: @WhozCraig it doesn't work.

Comment: Show by example what are you trying to do.

Comment: @JohnnyTran Works for me: http://ideone.com/eqmPHd

Comment: code im using it in posted above @Atomic_alarm

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie didnt work out in mine. i put my code above.

Comment: @JohnnyTran `std::accumulate` works every time.  The problem is the *data* you're providing it.  When that line executes, what does the `acct` list have in it?  Did you check?  Also, why are you accumulating `double` values and storing the total in an `int`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oops yeah i messed up on storing it as int instead of the double. I did check what I have in the list by printing it out and they are the doubles I put into it. but what happens when I print the line with sum in it, it just prints what was in the list and nothing adds at all.

Comment: @JohnnyTran You need to check again.  There is nothing wrong with `accumulate`.  It is your data that is at fault.  http://ideone.com/gQlqy8

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmm, ok I will see what may be wrong with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Move `list<double> acct;` *above* your for-loop; not within it.

Comment: @JohnnyTran could you please mark my answer as the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to sum the contents of a list

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList;
    myList.push_back(1);
    myList.push_back(2);
    myList.push_back(3);
    myList.push_back(4);
    int result = std::accumulate(std::begin(myList), std::end(myList), 0);
    std::cout << result; // Prints 10 on screen
}
```